# How to make Gridview cell clickable except for first cell

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am using an html grid.I want to make all the the cells of gridview clickable except for the cells in the first column.How can i make it possible with jQuery?

This is the code i have written for making all the cells in the gridview clickable

```
$("#gdTable tr:has(td)").click(function (e) {
    selTD = $(e.target).closest("td");
    selTR = $(e.target).closest("td").parent();;
    if (selTD.hasClass("selected")) selTD.removeClass("selected");
    else {
        selTR.children().removeClass("selected");
        selTD.addClass("selected");
    }
    getCellValue();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) along with [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) or [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/43ENx/1/)**

```
$("#gdTable td:not(:first-child)").click(function (e) {
    selTD = $(e.target).closest("td");
    selTR = $(e.target).closest("td").parent();;
    if (selTD.hasClass("selected")) selTD.removeClass("selected");
    else {
        selTR.children().removeClass("selected");
        selTD.addClass("selected");
    }
    getCellValue();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...But the above code makes only the first cell of the first column non clickable.

Comment: I changed the selector and used nth-child

Comment: Sorry mate.. i tried the code $("#gdTable tr td:not(nth-child(1))"),but now all the rows are clickable

Comment: Sorry mate there were typo in selector, I added live demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing just your selector this way:

```
$("#gdTable tr:has(td)").each(function () {
   $("td:not(:first)", this).click(function (e) {
        selTD = $(e.target).closest("td");
        selTR = $(e.target).closest("td").parent();;
        if (selTD.hasClass("selected")) {
          selTD.removeClass("selected");
        } else {
          selTR.children().removeClass("selected");
          selTD.addClass("selected");
        }
        getCellValue();
   });
});
```

[A small demo in fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PKHL4/)